# Asymptotic runtime behavior

Tags: algorithm

how can I can find the asymptotic runtime behavior of any algorithm?

Comment: Do you really mean 'of any algorithm'?  Isn't that kind of wide-open?  Isn't this more of a mathematical question more than a programming one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to derive a formula for the number of steps an algorithm takes in its loops/recursions in terms of the size of the input n and then take the summation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms has an example.